# Screen is not updating during function, won't display loading gif

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display a loading gif whilst an algorithm runs for around 5 seconds.

I run $('#loading-container').show() at the start of the function (before the algorithm runs) and $('#loading-container').hide() at the end, but nothing is displayed. If I set a timeout on the hide, then once the algorithm has finished I can see the gif running. I've also tried different ways to test if the code is being run, such as replacing text on a div that has the same issue, it only updates once the algorithm has run.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why it's not displaying? I imagine that all of the screen changes are processed at the end of the algorithm running and the gif is being hidden immediately.

```
function mycode() {
    $('#loading-container').show()
    // do lots of code
    $('#loading-container').hide()
}

// this code will show the gif
function mycode() {
    $('#loading-container').show()
    // do lots of code
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#loading-container').hide()
    }, 5000);
}
```

CSS

```
        #loading-container {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            margin: 0;
            z-index: 9998;
        }

        .loading {
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            z-index: 9999;
        }

        .loading img {
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            height: 100px;
        }
```

HTML

```
    <div id="loading-container" style="display: none;">
        <div class="loading">
            <img src="assets/loading-buffering.gif" alt="Loading...">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: _"Does anyone have any ideas as to why it's not displaying?"_ - **because** "an algorithm runs for around 5 seconds". That means, the JS engine will keep control, and not hand it back to the rendering engine, for as long as your continuous JS is running. In some situations querying an element's dimensions can help (read access to `someElement.offsetHeight` for example), but sometimes it is necessary to introduce a "break", by triggering the long running part after showing the icon, using setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame, in the first place.

Comment: Or you put the long running stuff into a Webworker, that would also be a possible solution. Plenty to find about this here on SO already, https://www.google.com/search?q=update+ui+while+js+is+running+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: Your code does a request, or processe0o,me huge stuff? How can we know this proccess don't take some seconds and that's less time than it takes to load the loading gif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the browser is executing those synchronously in a main thread. You can try to only run your synchronous code after 1 cycle of painting by making use of `requestAnimationFrame`:

```js
function mycode() {
  $('#loading-container').show();
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      // do lots of code
      $('#loading-container').hide();
    });
  });
}
```

(The reason why we need to call it twice instead of once is because `requestAnimationFrame` callback before the next re-paint happens, so we need to ensure the `loading-container` have the opportunity to re-paint first. The second call ensure the first re-paint has completed)